# How to combine two queries togather?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to combine two quires into one. That first quire is to get the user who is around the location of 3KM and second query is to sort where they work.
so I want to join both quires so that I can get people who work in specific company around 3KM.
And work is an column which has the various company names.

http://victorybro.esy.es/LocateMe/locateNearme.php?work[]=HCL&work[]=DELL

This link gives: "Query Failed!"

Here is my Php Code:

```
<?php

          $con = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.in", "u408122646_chat", "123", "u408122646_chat");

    $work  = $_GET['work'];
    $locate_me = array();

    foreach ($_REQUEST['work'] as $key => $val) {
    $locate_me[$key] = filter_var($val, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
    $works = "'" . implode("','", $locate_me) . "'";

$sql="SELECT id,latitude,londitude, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(12.95665699) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( londitude ) - radians(80.23708535) ) + sin( radians(12.95665699) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM locate_me HAVING distance < 1 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM locate_me WHERE work IN ({$works})";


    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);   

if(!$res)
{
      die("Query Failed!");
} $response["success"] = true;
     $response= array();
 while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $response[] = $row;}


echo json_encode(array("response"=>$response));
 mysqli_free_result($res);

 ?>
```

Comment: while using `union` make sure that the separate queries generate same number of columns.

Comment: use `mysqli_error($con)` to get the error message. All select statments must return the same number of columns

Comment: (1) When doing a `union` between `select`s the selects must be union compatible (have the same number of columns) (2) You cannot use `having` without `group by`. (3) you need to revisit your logic because chances are you can do what you need in a single select

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need, the SQL can be written as:

```
$myLocLat = 12.95665699;
$myLocLon = 80.23708535;

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT 
    id, 
    latitude,
    londitude, 
    (6371 * acos(cos(radians($myLocLat)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(londitude) - radians($myLocLon)) + sin(radians($myLocLat)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance 
FROM locate_me 
WHERE distance < 1 
      AND work IN ($works) 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20  
SQL;
```

Note that in MySQL 5.7.6+ you can get the distance between two points by:

```
ST_Distance(Point(lon1,lat1),Point(lon2,lat2))
```

Something to look into if you want to not deal with formulae to determine distances.

Comment: how we can able to print data from $sql.? thank you

Comment: Doesn't your current code already do that? You just need to replace your current `$sql = ...` with the code block here.